# Вращение объекта в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

подскажите пожалуйста, как можно через скрипт узнать на какой угол повернут игровой объект по оси X? Т.е. имеется объект Directional Light, который вращается по оси X на каждом кадре, начиная от 0, что выглядит так:

```
public int flash;

void Start()
{
       
}

void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(0.005f, 0f, 0f);
    if (...)
        flash++;
}
```

Мне необходимо узнать, когда объект повернется, скажем, на 180 градусов по оси X и в этот момент присвоить flash единицу. Думаю для этой задачи нужен if в методе Update, но что нужно написать в самом этом условии? Спасибо.

Comment: Нужно знать что такое sin, cos и pi, а так-же уметь находить угол вектора через арктангенс atan. Без этого про написание игр можно забыть.

Comment: @Yaroslav, хорошо, а можно тогда как-то узнать через код значение угла поворота объекта по оси Х, то которое отображается в transform.rotation в инспекторе?

Comment: Безусловно можно! С помощью вышеупомянутого арктангенса `Mathf.Atan2`.

Answer (score 0):

Получить координаты **Rotation** мы можем так:

```
transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x //x
transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y //y
transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z //z
```

В вашем случае код будет такой:

```
void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(0.005f, 0f, 0f);
    if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x == 180)
        flash++;
}
```

[Почитать об transform.rotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html)

Comment: Так-же, вам нужно продумать систему сброса Rotate, если хотите что бы каждые 180 градусов переменная flash увеличивалась на 1, ибо если использовать метод transform.Rotate, то переменна Rotate, при достижении 360 градусов не сбрасывается, а продолжает увеличиваться

Comment: спасибо за ответ про координаты, в методе Start скрипта для Directional Light написал Vector3 rotaion = transform.rotation.eulerAngles; в инспекторе указывается поворот по иксу от 0 до 180 и обратно, после чего повторяется, т.е. больше 180 поворот не указывается.